How to resolve a Javascript error on Event setup?
This is a fairly longstanding problem on a D7/Civi site that I'd love to sort out. The site runs a lot of events using CiviCRM. The Online Registration tab for event configuration should present a drop-down to enable me to choose profiles to include on my registration form, but all I see is a text field (I can enter the profile ID and this works), and it won't let me add another profile.
Also the fields for introductory text and footer text, which should bring up CKEditor when clicked into, are just text fields, as is the confirmation email text field.
The browser console reports an error:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'date_format.indexOf')
and shows a reference to https://myseite.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
What might be causing this problem, and what steps can I take to fix it?

Are you using Angular profile extension?

No. Should I be?
